# Argument 'algorithm' passed by position and keyword in method callp

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a class and call it this is my code

```
import jwt


class generate_jwt():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'jwt token manager'

    def encode_with_hsa(self, secret, expiration_time, payload):
        exp_time = {'exp': expiration_time}
        return jwt.encode(payload, exp_time, secret, algorithm='HS256')

snake = generate_jwt()
so = {'secret':'ff'}
print(snake.encode_with_hsa('dd', 434234, so))
```

But this shows TypeError: encode() got multiple values for argument 'algorithm' when calling the class and returing the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code by doing something like:

```
import jwt
class generate_jwt():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'jwt token manager'

    def encode_with_hsa(self, secret, expiration_time, payload):
        exp_time = {'exp': expiration_time}
        return jwt.encode(payload, secret, algorithm='HS256', exp_time)

snake = generate_jwt()
so = {'secret':'ff'}
print(snake.encode_with_hsa('dd', 434234, so))
```

Checkout the definition of encode function [here](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/blob/master/jwt/api_jwt.py#L40/#LC40):

> ```
> def encode(self,
>                payload,  # type: Union[Dict, bytes]
>                key,  # type: str
>                algorithm='HS256',  # type: str
>                headers=None,  # type: Optional[Dict]
>                json_encoder=None  # type: Optional[Callable]
>                ):
> ```

So, you have to go by the definition of the function, i.e. how the arguments are passed (order of the arguments).

Note: I am not sure where you need the `exp_time`. You can just remove it as it is optional.

Comment: So how will I set expiration time for a token in pyjwt?

Comment: You can find more info on that in the documentation: https://pyjwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#expiration-time-claim-exp

Comment: Jithin, if you have more followup questions, you should consider creating a new question. Someone else would ans you quickly.